# Why do people in the Arrowverse reference Marvel?

Tags: marvel, dc, arrowverse, the-flash-2014

While watching the Flash season 3 episode 5, I just saw Felicity Smoak reference “The Incredible Hulk”.

Then, after doing some research, I found out that’s also happened often on other shows of the Arrowverse.

I find it extremely odd with Marvel and DC being kind of rivals in the business. It’s like doing marketing for you competition.

What’s the reason behind those references instead of referencing DC superheroes?

Comment: Cause DC is real... Marvel is pretend...

Comment: I mean literally why in terms of business reasons and motivations. It feels to me like quoting abc channel on a cbs show for example.

Comment: I think DC and Marvel are rivals like Microsoft and Apple. (Did you know Microsoft bailed out Apple back in the day so they could stay in business?) They need each other to push each other and get better themselves... I'm sure that they are referring to Marvel as a gentle nod. Admitting that Marvel (your rival) exists isn't illegal or bad practice. It is acknowledging that both your companies exist and that fans of one can (and often are) fans of the other as well. No real real downside referencing each other... IMO

Comment: I’m 99% sure this is a dupe

Comment: It’s not a duplicate of that one. I was aware of that other question and I understand why there’re no legal implications from using it. I just found it very weird for DC to reference Marvel. So far Odín’s comment sounds quite reasonable.

Comment: If they reference a DC property, they risk creating a continuity error down the line or implying that a DC character, one you might want to use in the future, is fictional, or well-known enough to be a pop-culture reference that everyone is expected to 'get'.  If they reference Marvel, it's not a problem.  If they mention Image, then the audience will have no idea who they are or what the reference means.

Comment: The companies are competitors, but the people writing the show (and writing/drawing the comics) are just people. I doubt anybody at DC hates Marvel enough to enact a "no mentioning Marvel ever" rule. What would be the point? I doubt anybody was watching Flash, saw Felicity mention the Hulk, and say "I know! I'll stop buying DC comics and only buy Marvel comics from now on!"

Comment: There was a Spider-Man reference in a Legends of Tomorrow episode this season.

Comment: In the minds of the public, it's not always been clear that Spider-Man, the Hulk, and the X-Men belong to a different company than Batman, Superman, and Wonder Woman do.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's been a long tradition that characters in one comic company make explicit reference to characters in another comic company, based on the premise that "our" characters are in the "real world" and those characters are fictional and in comic books.

So in the Arrowverse there's Marvel comics, and the Marvel movies, and the Incredible Hulk TV show from the 1970s, and Spider-Man cartoons, and the lame live-action Spider-Man series from the 1970s, and *Jessica Jones* on HBO, and people watch and reference them just like they do *Game of Thrones* or *Star Wars*.

And although it's not come up in the Marvel Cinematic Universe, people there might be watching *Arrow* and *The Flash*, going out to see *Wonder Woman* in theaters, and arguing over just how much *Dawn of Justice* sucked.

Comment: This answer can be improved by adding examples of this being a "long tradition", rather than just the arrowverse.

Comment: Note there are also, let's call them *implicit* references. Example: Thor wearing glasses as a part of his "Sigurd Jarlson" secret identity during the Walt Simonson run. I don't think they explicitly say "Superman" or "Clark Kent', but it's clear that they're thinking of him.